# User editing a tag wiki stating it should not be used

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

I was going through the suggested edit review queue when I found [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1758247):

> Do not use this tag, use the **MPMoviePlayerController** tag instead.

I must say I have no idea about neither of those tags, but my question is: is that really what one should do? Shouldn't it instead just be retagged (only 247 questions) if that other tag really is better or more correct in some way?

Also: how should I handle those edit reviews (i.e. what action should I take)?

Comment: I saw that. I rejected it and told him to post on meta/retag the questions. (Although that was the first tag wiki I ever reviewed so I could be wrong (yay 5k rep `:P`))

Comment: Note that, in this case, the excerpt already says the same thing.

Comment: Nice catch. Also by the same user.

Comment: If this does come up, the two are **very** separate things in the iPhone world. They should not be merged whatsoever.